# How to make a python request to a S3 presigned url and get access to its content?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

So I am a bit lost on how to make a python request to an already S3 presigned url and download its content because I do see that the presigned url also has an `AWS access key id`, `expiration time`, `.json`, `response-content-disposition`,`response-content-type`, and `Signature`. The bucket for the presigned url I am trying to access is an internal bucket and I don't want to be generating a new presigned url.

Example presigned url link:

```
https://video_annotations.s3.amazonaws.com/folder1/annotations/sub-folder1/9162dn28sd78n.json?respone-content-disposition=attachment$6B%50filename%9D812jad9.json&respone-content-type=application%3Fjson&AWSAccessKeyID=different_aws_access_key_id&Signature=pAKSR97&Expires=1661271906
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should be able to make an HTTP request with the `requests` library and load the text content, like `json.loads(requests.get('s3-presigned-url').text)`.

Comment: Thank you. Did not know that you can just put a `s3-presigned-url` like that.